# Is there a special term for when a noun is used to describe another noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, terminology

Is there a term for when a noun is used as an adjective, as in:

- Click the button to open the *configuration* dialog.
- I need to stop at the *car* wash.
- The *train* station is right next to the *bus* station.
- Do you have documentation for the *setup* process?
- I'm throwing a party, and the entire *ELU* community is invited.
- Hopefully, the party won't get busted by the *grammar* police again.

Is there a word to describe that?

Also, are those even adjectives? Or are they adverbs or something?

(I feel like this must be a duplicate (?) but I could only find questions about when adjectives are used as nouns, not the other way around...)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice find thank you. The question isn't as direct but [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/446848/55308) definitely covers it, although not as nicely as [Jake Frandsen's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/525658/55308) below. The short answer though is: Yup, it answers my question. I'm going to let community CVs decide this one for me, I'm kind of torn. Thanks!!

Comment: There are many other similar threads. [What grammatical role is 'blood' playing in the phrase 'blood red'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510618/what-grammatical-role-is-blood-playing-in-the-phrase-blood-red/510648#510648), [What part of speech is 'mountain' in the sentence ... dangerous to mountain climbers'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499137/what-part-of-speech-is-mountain-in-the-sentence-avalanches-are-dangerous-to-m), ...

Comment: [Is this noun used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective), [What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/what-is-the-word-that-denotes-the-words-preceding-these-nouns/15712#15712).... (possibly the first example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several terms for this: attributive noun, qualifying noun, noun adjunct, noun modifier. ("Adjectival noun" is an older term for it as well.)

It is still a noun—not an adjective or adverb—but it's used to modify another noun an way similar to what adjectives do.

An adjective can be used after the noun: The large station / the station is large

But an attributive noun can't: The train station / *The station is train

Comment: Not a foolproof test; a nuclear explosion / an electrical storm.

Comment: Hmm. It seems grammatical to me to say, "The explosion was nuclear" or "The storm was electrical." Awkward, yes. Ungrammatical, I don't think so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hm, yeah, I'm stupid but I have to agree with Jake on that test. "The explosion is nuclear" is weird but still makes sense, otoh with a ... wait for it ...  **qualifying noun**  as in "population explosion", "the explosion is population" doesn't make sense any more. The test still checks out in both cases.

Comment: 'The explosion is nuclear' is non-standard. Some adjectives (eg 'mere', 'elder', 'former', 'chemical', ) are well recognised to be attributive-only (just as there are a few that are predicative only, like 'awake', 'alert', 'aloof', 'unaware'). And try making sense of 'The man was mere' from 'He was a mere man'.  There can be problems with some words in deciding whether a premodifier is an adjective or an attributive noun (a fun party, a steel bridge are two examples that grammarians have studied in depth).

Answer (score 0):

The nouns in your examples are not really used as an adjectives; they are used as nominal modifiers, and those can either be adjectives or nouns. In the latter case there is a grey area with compound nouns.

In some grammatical approaches there is a distinction between form (adjective) and function (modifier); different forms can fulfill a particular function.

Most of your examples I would actually classify as compound nouns.

Comment: I didn't even know "modifiers" were a thing; I'll go read more. Where is the line between a noun with a modifier and a compound noun (or is that enough for a new question)?

Comment: It depends on the grammatical theory; some more traditional approaches might have different terminology. The line between nominal modifiers and compound nouns is fluid. If a particular combination is used frequently, it tends to be seen as a compound. Can be quite subjective.